# symfony - pass field entity from array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i have the following route that displays a list of posts
this list of posts also shows the category of the post
each category has a parent category
what i want is to show in a twig template the parent category that each posts corresponds to.
my failed attempt is $rnc var which i only did it for a dump test

```
/**
 * @Route("/agency", name="agency_admin")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function listAction ()
{
    $agency = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    $ads = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:AdsList');
    $ad = $ads->findBy(array('postedBy' => $agency));
    $rnx = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CategoryAd');
    $rnc = $rnx->findBy(array('parentCat' => $ad));
    return $this->render('agency/index.html.twig', [
        'user'  => $agency,
        'posts' => $ad,
    ]);
}
```

**CategoryAd** Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\MainCategory", inversedBy="subCat")
 */
private $parentCat;
```

**MainCategory** Entity

```
/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CategoryAd", mappedBy="parentCat")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $subCat;
```

i only posted the related fields from each Entity
i hope i posted enough data. thank in advance

LE:

```
class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
/**
 * @param CategoryAd $subCat
 * @return CategoryAd[]
 */
public function findAllParentCat(CategoryAd $pc)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('ads_category_main')
        ->andWhere('ads_category_main.subcat = :sc')
        ->setParameter('sc', $pc)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
}
```

Comment: I assume `$ad` contains a list of ads posted by the current user. If these ads has a relation to category, and each category has a relation to its parent category, you should be able to do this in twig with just `{% for post in posts %}Post {{ post.id }} has category {{ post.category.id }} ({{ post.category.parentCat.id }}{% endfor %}` Note that this will require multiple queries to run in each iteration of the loop. You would be better off making a custom repository method to fetch a users ads while joining in the categories.

Comment: i tried to make a custom repository ( i will update the code in the question )

i cant figure out how to pass the argument - symfony trows something like catchable fatal error -- array problem

Comment: I suggest you make the repository method in the repository for the ads. If you there just join in the relations to the category/parent category you should get what you want from that repo only.

Comment: any new ideas ?

Comment: No I'm quite confident the way I've described it is the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion. Ideally, you should have had one category table with the self reference to it. This is how you can query for it. I am imagining that in the AdsList table you have reference to the CategoryAds Table.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CategoryAd")
 */
private $categoryAd;
```

Then, Your controller should look like this

```
public function listAction ()
{
    $agency = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    $ads = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:AdsList');
    $ad = $ads->findBy(array('postedBy' => $agency));
    return $this->render('agency/index.html.twig', [
        'user'  => $agency,
        'posts'=> $ad,
    ]);
}
```

Your twig file should reference to subcategory and main category like this

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{post.categoryAd.name}} {# assuming you have category name #}
    {{post.categoryAd.parentCat.name}} {# assuming you have main category name #}
{% endfor%}
```